# Android - Can't complete if statement

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can't complete my if statement in android. I am trying to open a url with a edit text and i cant complete my if statement!!

```
searchbar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String url = searchbar.getText().toString();
            if (searchbar.getText().toString().contains("http://")) ;
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }






        }
    });
```

Comment: remove semicolon in if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to delete ";" that you have at the end of the if statement line

from

```
if (searchbar.getText().toString().contains("http://")) ;
```

to

```
if (searchbar.getText().toString().contains("http://"))
```

Comment: please close the question if this answered your question :)